# Toggle switch slider position is out of order

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to create a toggle switch described as [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch). But I want to be my slider look like [image: ok] [image: notok]

All I can come up with

[image]  [image]

Background color is not important the position of the slider is.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it'd be better if you add your code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: -3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border:solid 2px #000;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>


  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am glad that helped :)

Answer (score 3):

w3school example working fine.

check fiddle below:

```css
/* for the lazy */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  transition: 400ms all ease-in-out 50ms;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

a{ color: rgba(43,43,43,1); text-decoration: none; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(43,43,43,1); }

a:hover{ background: rgba(43,43,43,1); color: rgba(255,255,255,1); }


/*Button is :CHECKED*/

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div {
  background: rgba(73,168,68,1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(73,168,68,1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div label {
  left: 110px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}


/*shared*/

div,
label {
  border-radius: 50px;
}


/*'un':checked state*/

div {
  height: 70px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  left: calc(50vw - 100px);
  
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(43,43,43,1);
  
}

label {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
position: absolute;
top: -15px;
left: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(43,43,43,1);
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  height: 60px;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label::after {
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label::before,
label::after{
  background: rgba(43,43,43,1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* pesduo class on toggle */

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div label::before{
  height: 50px;
  top: calc(55% - 25px);
  left: calc(60% - 2.5px);
  background: rgba(73,168,68,1);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div label::after{
  width: 20px;
  top: calc(95% - 25px);
  left: calc(22.5% - 2.5px);
  background: rgba(73,168,68,1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
<div>
  <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not that. i want my slider described as the image around the switch border not inside them.

Comment: this is a much better solution then what i asked for but breaks my pages design to pieces. thank you anyway.

Comment: @RaihanRidoy convert my css into class. give name for div label